# Javascript round up to nearest .5

Tags: javascript, rounding

How can I round a number up to the nearest .5?  For example:

```
5.4 -> 5.5
5.6 -> 6
6.1 -> 6.5
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
var number = 5.1;
var roundednumber = Math.round(number*2)/2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's what the [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) (ceiling) method is for:

> The `Math.ceil(x)` function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a number "x".

For example:

```
var number = 5.1;
var roundednumber = Math.ceil(number*2)/2; // 5.5
```

But note that it will also round negative numbers up (more positive):

```
var number = -5.1;
var roundednumber = Math.ceil(number*2)/2; // -5
```

If you want to round away from 0, you'd have to do something like this:

```
var number = -5.1;
var roundednumber = (number > 0 ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(number*2)/2; // -5.5
```